# is it possible to run photoshop action or batch from vba

Tags: excel, vba

is it possible to run photoshop action from vba? if it is, how?

Answer (score 0):

If the remote process supports some kind of IPC, or you can use parameters on start to execute your request, then yes.

As far as I know, Photoshop does support COM indetop, thus you should be able to automate it from VBA. However, there can be limitations compared to GUI manipulation. Check this document: https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/photoshop/pdfs/photoshop-cc-scripting-guide-2019.pdf especially the chapter *Viewing Photoshop's type library* on page 22, but actually the whole document is the answer to your question.

Comment: Thanks for answer, could you please do an example for me

Comment: The document contains examples. I dont have Photoshop on my PC, thus I cant.